# Почему masm ругается на string or text literal too long и почему в структуре выставляется db или dw?

Tags: c, masm32, masm

Я пишу с-шеллкод по [этому](https://forum.reverse4you.org/t/shellcode-windows-0x01/685) примеру. Повторяю действия из примера по заполнению структуры:
Сам пример:

```
    ;IA86 and AMD64
    IFDEF _M_IA86
    .386
    .model flat, stdcall
    ENDIF

    ;set code section .shell
    .CODE shell

    ;data struct
    Shell_Static_Data STRUCT 
        phrase_ldrloaddll db 16 dup(0)
        phrase_msgbox db 16 dup(0) //почему byte?
        phrase_hello db 16 dup(0)
        phrase_hello_title db 16 dup(0)
        phrase_user32 dw 16 dup(0)//почему word? 
        phrase_ntdll dw 16 dup(0)
    Shell_Static_Data ENDS

    shelldata Shell_Static_Data <"LdrLoadDll", "MessageBoxA", "Hello hacker", "Shellcode", \
         {'u', 's', 'e', 'r', '3', '2', '.', 'd', 'l', 'l'}, {'N', 't', 'd', 'l','l', '.', 'd', 'l', 'l'}>
;getting ptr to shelldata struct

IFDEF _M_IA86

get_data_struct_ptr PROC
;delta
    call get_delta
get_delta:
    pop eax
;calc var
    sub eax, 5
    sub eax, sizeof shelldata
    ret
get_data_struct_ptr ENDP

ELSEIFDEF _M_AMD64

get_data_struct_ptr PROC
;delta
    call get_delta
get_delta:
    pop rax
;calc var
    sub rax, 5
    sub rax, sizeof shelldata
    ret
get_data_struct_ptr ENDP

ENDIF

END
```

Почему выставляются именно db или dw. Как это связанно с размером массива,объявляемого в структуре на Си?
В соответствие этому ассемблерному коду записывается структура на Си:

```
 #pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct _Shell_Static_Data {
    char phrase_ldrloaddll[16];
    char phrase_msgbox[16];
    char phrase_hello[16];
    char phrase_hello_title[16];
    wchar_t phrase_user32[16];
    wchar_t phrase_ntdll[16];
} Shell_Static_Data, *PShell_Static_Data;
#pragma pack(pop)

extern PShell_Static_Data __stdcall get_data_struct_ptr();

__declspec(noinline) void entry();

void *get_module_base_addr(wchar_t *mod_name);
void *get_proc_addr(void *mod_addr, char *proc_name);
```

Пример рабочий и он запускается по инструкции.

Теперь я пишу свой аналог,основываясь на этот пример:
MASM:

```
     ;IA86 and AMD64
        IFDEF _M_IA86
        .386
        .model flat, stdcall
        ENDIF

        ;set code section .shell
        .CODE shell

        ;data struct
        Shell_Static_Data STRUCT 
            phrase_ldrloaddll db 16 dup(0)
            phrase_ntdll dw 16 dup(0)
            phrase_kernel32 dw 16 dup(0)
            phrase_FindFirFil db 16 dup(0)
            phrase_FindNexFileA db 16 dup(0)
            phrase_DelFilA db 16 dup(0)
            phrase_FindCL db 16 dup(0)
            phrase_ExPr db 16 dup(0)
            phrase_PathM db 42 dup(0) ;не понимаю какое число нужно выставлять, это зависит от размера массива?
    ;что нужно выбрать db или dw, может dt ? На чём завязан этот выбор?
            phrase_path db 38 dup(0)
        Shell_Static_Data ENDS

        shelldata Shell_Static_Data <"LdrLoadDll", {'N','t','d','l','l','.','d','l','l'},{'K','e','r','n','e','l','3','2','.','d','l','l'},"FindFirstFileA","FindNextFileA","DeleteFileA","FindClose","ExitProcess","C:\\Users\\Documents\\delete\\d*.*","C:\\Users\\Documents\\delete\\">
;getting ptr to shelldata struct

IFDEF _M_IA86

get_data_struct_ptr PROC
;delta
    call get_delta
get_delta:
    pop eax
;calc var
    sub eax, 5
    sub eax, sizeof shelldata
    ret
get_data_struct_ptr ENDP

ELSEIFDEF _M_AMD64

get_data_struct_ptr PROC
;delta
    call get_delta
get_delta:
    pop rax
;calc var
    sub rax, 5
    sub rax, sizeof shelldata
    ret
get_data_struct_ptr ENDP

ENDIF

END
```

Здесь я пытаюсь по аналогии с примера записать свои функции и строки(так как указателями в турториале запретили пользоваться по причине прямых ссылок, а в шеллкоде такое нельзя)
Мне не понятно, как записываются поля структуры на ассемблере: как понять нужен db или dw, какое число за ним следует, каким оно должно быть и от чего это зависит(может от количества символов в кавычках?) 
Структура на Си выглядит так:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct _Shell_Static_Data {
    char phrase_ldrloaddll[16];
    wchar_t phrase_ntdll[16];
    wchar_t phrase_kernel32[16];
    char phrase_FindFirFil[16];//findfirstfilea
    char phrase_FindNexFileA[16];
    char phrase_DelFilA[16];
    char phrase_FindCL[16];//findclose
    char phrase_ExPr[16];//exitproc
    char phrase_PathM[42];//путь с маской
    char phrase_path[38];
} Shell_Static_Data, *PShell_Static_Data;
#pragma pack(pop)

extern PShell_Static_Data __stdcall get_data_struct_ptr();

__declspec(noinline) void entry();
```

С выставленными текущими параметрами VS говорит,что :

A2041   string or text literal too long
(shellcode_native.asm)

A2006   undefined symbol : shelldata

Помогите разобраться с ошибками

Comment: `db` vs. `dw` -- это слишком очевидно. Просто `sizeof(type)`. Windows `wchar_t` -- 16-битный тип. Можете всё в байтах писать.

Comment: Потом у вас параметры попутаны. Вы вообще понимаете как динамическая загрузка работает? В вашем примере вы пытаетесь что именно сделать? Несколько функций за раз выполнить? А потом, вы читали ABI на вот это вот всё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь:

```
 shelldata Shell_Static_Data <"LdrLoadDll", {'N','t','d','l','l','.','d','l','l'},{'K','e','r','n','e','l','3','2','.','d','l','l'},"FindFirstFileA","FindNextFileA","DeleteFileA","FindClose","ExitProcess","C:\\Users\\Documents\\delete\\d*.*","C:\\Users\\Documents\\delete\\">
```

Абсолютные пути нужно было писать `C:\Users\Documents\delete\` , а не с двумя слеш